# Inference from Wronskian determinant to 2nd order linear homogeneous ordinary differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know that the equation of a homogeneous linear ODE2 is
$$y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0$$

I know that the Wronskian of two solutions is a determinant of a matrix.
$$W=\det\pmatrix{y_1 & y_2 \\ y_1' & y_2'} .$$

What is the logic leading to the statement?
$$y''+ \frac1{x} y'- {4\over x^2} y = 0$$

This is discussed in Trench: *Elementary Differential Equations*, section 5.1.

Thank you. MM

Comment: What statement?

Comment: The ode is cauchy euler https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation

Comment: I was trying to work backward to the two solutions y1 and y2. I did not recognize the differential equation as a Euler-Cauchy equation which is a linear homogeneous ordinary differential equation with variable coefficients. The solution comes down to solving a quadratic equation. When I looked at WIKI they suggested 3 possible solutions (2 distinct, 1 real repeated, or complex roots).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last ODE is singular in $x=0$. Any statement about solutions is only valid over the interval $(0,\infty)$.

As the ODE is of Euler-Cauchy type, it is easy to identify the basis solutions $x^2,x^{-2}$. Their Wronskian is
$$
W=x^2⋅(-2x^{-3})-2x\cdot x^{-2}=-4x^{-1}.
$$
This, as expected, is a non-zero function over $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Is this not also a non-zero function over (-inf,0)?

Comment: Yes, and the ODE is invariant under sign change in $x$. But usually, if not indicated otherwise, the domain is in the positive direction.